# The function sent to the component in React does not execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used a component inside the project to display the input, and I wrote that component as follows, both to add "task" and to edit it.

```js
//Input component-----------------------------
import React from 'react';

const Input = ({ placeHolder, operation, addTask, editTask, taskId }) => {

    let button = "";

    switch (operation) {
        case "add":
            button = <button className="btn btn-success" style={{ width: "10%" }} id="btnAddTask" onClick={addTask}>Add</button>;
            break;

        case "edit":
            button = <button className="btn btn-warning" style={{ width: "10%" }} onClick={() => editTask(taskId)}>Edit</button>;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return (
        <div className="input-bar row container" >
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={placeHolder}
                className="form-control"
                id="txtTask"
                style={{ width: "40%", marginRight: "5px" }}
            />

            <input
                type="time"
                className="form-control"
                style={{ width: "40%", marginRight: "5px" }}
                id="taskTime"
            />

            {button}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input;

//state---------------------------------------
state = {
        tasks: [],
        taskID: 1,
        isEditing: false,
        isDone: false,
        
        inputs: <Input
            placeHolder="Task Description"
            operation="add"
            addTask={this.AddTask}
            editTask={this.EditTask} />,
        
        taskId: 0
    }
    
//the function that changes the state(to re-render the Input component)--------------
ChangeInput = id => {
        let input;
        conts txtTask = document.getElementById("txtTask");
        const taskTime = document.getElementById("taskTime");

        if (this.state.isEditing) {
            input = <Input
                placeHolder="Task Description"
                operation="add"
                addTask={this.AddTask}
                editTask={this.EditTask}
            />;

            txtTask.value = "";
            taskTime.value = "";

            this.setState({inputs: input, isEditing: false});
        } else {
            input = <Input
                placeHolder="Task Description"
                operation="edit"
                addTask={this.AddTask}
                editTask={this.EditTask}
                taskId={this.state.taskId}
            />;

            txtTask.value = this.state.tasks?.find(t=> t.taskID === id).taskDes;
            taskTime.value = this.state.tasks?.find(t => t.taskID === id).time;

            this.setState({inputs: input, isEditing: true, taskId: id});
        }
    }

//render part ---------------------------
render() { 
        const { DeleteTask, ChangeInput, DoneTask } = this;
        const { inputs, tasks } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="container" onKeyPress={event => this.SubmitForm(event)}>
                <br/>
                <h2
                    style={{
                        textAlign: "center" 
                    }}
                    className="display-3">Task Manager</h2>
                <br />
                
                //Input Component
                {inputs}
                
                <hr/>

                <br/>
    
                <Tasks
                    tasks={tasks}
                    deleteTask={DeleteTask}
                    changeInput={ChangeInput}
                    doneTask={DoneTask}
                />
    
                <ToastContainer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The problem is that the component is displayed by default(has been set in state)but the function i sent to component to add task isn't working at all

But when I call **"changeInput" function** and turn it to "add" mode again(from edit mode , using `setState()`), it works fine!

> I have copied the "Input" component calling part from **changeInput** to **state** to make sure it's the same from syntax

Comment: where are you rendering `Input`? I don't see it.

Comment: id suggest using the `useState()` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: @ChristianFritz sorry , question edited .

Comment: don't put your component in the state. It really doesn't belong there.

Comment: @ChristianFritz so, how can call `Input` component in `App.js` (parent component) so i can change it to **edit Input** component by calling `changeInput` function ?